# How do I get the text to be flush with one side of the cube?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-editing

My graphic designer left our organization, and my Photoshop abilities less advanced. I'm having trouble figuring out how to make the letters flush with the sides of the cube.

The .psd file I have does not have a 3D layer, just the sides. I'm sure it's something simple, but it eludes me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to accomplish this, but I think the easiest/fastest approach is to simply select the layer with the text (by the way if it IS actually text then right click and hit "rasterise").

Then hit "Edit" > "Transform" > "Distort" and simply drag the four corner handles of the bounding box to the four corners of the face of the cube you are working on. (See video below)

Then hit "Edit" > "Free transform", and, holding the shift key and control keys while you drag, size the letter a little smaller than the face. (The shift locks the ratio, the control key locks the centre)

Other methods include getting involved with the 3D functionality, face mapping etc. But I think this method should suffice.

[image]